# Visual Studio Breakpoint, click to disable, not to delete

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, toggle, breakpoints

By default, Visual Studio 2012, and others possibly, deletes an enabled breakpoint upon clicking it. This to me feels unnatural because clicking a disabled breakpoint enables it. Why then would a subsequent click delete it? I would expect the opposite, which is disabling the breakpoint, similar behaviour to Xcode.

Is there a setting somewhere that allows me to modify this behaviour, to clicking to toggle between enabled and disabled?

Comment: On VS 2019 this is still a thing. Why? Seems pretty dumb to be able to destroy something you may have put a considerable amount of work into with so little thought (for example by misclicking or the touchpad messing up a right click, both have happened to me).

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about a setting to change the single click behavior, but a little experimenting revealed that shift clicking the breakpoint disables instead of deletes it. this is in visual studio 2019. i found your question because i was wondering the same thing.